# Youtube Python API

Tags: python, api, binding, youtube, youtube-api

Is there a Python implementation of the Youtube API, other than the [gData](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) package?

I'm talking about something along the lines of the [Heroku](https://github.com/heroku/heroku.py) or [Github](https://github.com/dustin/py-github) Python bindings. The gData package seems to be unnecessarily complicated to work with and some of the interfaces only work with older API versions. That's not even mentioning the lack of clear, accessible documentation.

I'm wondering whether everyone just uses the gData package, or if something else exists.

Comment: I have always used the gData library.  I agree that there is a learning curve, but, I haven't found the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python) bad.

Comment: Maybe I'm spoiled by the standard of documentation Django/some-other-projects offers. Regardless, I took a couple of hours and put together an interface that works like a python interface should work.

My problem with the gData library is that it feels too much like I'm working with the (necessary) JSON lingo. It doesn't feel like it adds much on top of just raw JSON parsing.

Answer (score 3):

There's the general [Google API Client for Python](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/). We have samples for this [client here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python).